# MySQL multiple joins

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I'm making a request that looks like this:

```
SELECT main_table.*, <complicated calculation> AS computed_variable
FROM main_table
LEFT JOIN table1 ON main_table.id = table1.ref_id
LEFT JOIN table2 ON main_table.id = table2.ref_id
LEFT JOIN table3 ON main_table.id = table3.ref_id
GROUP BY main_table.id
HAVING computed_value > 1000
ORDER BY computed_variable ASC
```

The important part here is **complicated calculation**, which **SUMs** (something like this: SUM(table3.value * table3.duration)) over different *table3* columns. I should note that it is absolutely NOT possible to throw it away from this SQL, since it is used in *ordering* and *"having"* constraints

The problem I've never come across - two (or more) JOINS (table1, table2) make it so that SUM for table3 is incorrect.
According to what I know - all the table3 records are being used multiple times ->
COUNT(table1) * COUNT(table2) times, to be precise.

Correct me if I'm wrong.

So - the end value (computed_variable) is much greater than it should be.

Question is - how to fix this?

P.S table1 and table2 joins cannot be removed as well. I need them for other important calculations and constrains.

But they do not use any complicated aggregation functions, so it doesn't really matter if their records have duplicated.

Can anything be done about this problem?

P.S For those of you who wanted to see an example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/57333/4

Comment: shouldn't it also be grouped by a field of table 3? this sum with a group by main_table.id will always sum a single line

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier Well, I think I tried that already. It did not work.

Comment: it would help having the structure of your tables as the exact complicated calculation :). also if you can update your question with the group by you have tried

Comment: What you describe is a `cross join`, which cannot happen here, unless MySQL is exposing its usual random behaviour because of the badly written `group by` clause. Fix the code before fixing the symptoms I'd say - and then share all the information. What we see now is actually supposed to work as intended.

Comment: I'll include a "sqlfiddle" for showing an example.

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes included an example! Be sure to take a look if you are interested :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a problem of joining along multiple dimensions, which is multiplying the number of rows.  Assuming the complicated calculation is just from `table3` (*as you have described it in the question*), you can pre-aggregate the results:

```
SELECT m.*, <complicated calculation> AS computed_variable
FROM main_table m LEFT JOIN
     table1
     ON m.id = t1.ref_id LEFT JOIN
     table2
     ON m.id = t2.ref_id LEFT JOIN
     (select t3.ref_id, <complicated calculation> AS computed_variable
      table3 t3
      group by t3.ref_id
     ) t3
     ON m.id = t3.ref_id
GROUP BY m.id
HAVING computed_value > 1000
ORDER BY computed_variable ASC;
```

You may need to include more tables in the subquery, if they are needed for the calculation.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can use a sub-query for the join?  So, rather than joining the table, you join another select statement which includes the sum performed prior to the join.

e.g. something like:

```
LEFT JOIN (select *, -calculation- from table3) table3data on main_table.id = table3data.ref_id
```

Comment: The calculation would be done on table 3 prior to the joins, so it would be as if you were doing a select over that single table.  The table your are joining is then essentially a view which contains new calculated columns which are already correct.

Comment: To be clear, the critical part is that the subquery you join against includes the aggregate calculation/sum function, and it is simply referenced by your outer select statement.